# Why does the .done() method finish executing before the $getJSON calls finish executing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I have been having an issue where one of my methods is executing before my getJSON calls are finished executing.  This method needs the data from the calls before executing itself.

I have looked up a few things such as "deferred calls or .done(), but my main issue is that my nested getJSON calls are variable.  This means from my first file I get a number and with that number I create a loop and then do multiple getJSON calls based on that number.  I cannot attach a .done() because I have to do it multiple times, and a deferred call wont work for the same reason.  For some reason the first .done() doesn't wait until the inner getJSON calls finish before executing...  Is that supposed to happen?

```
       $.getJSON(file, function(d) 
    {

       for(var i = 0; i < d.name.length; i++)
       {
            files[i] = d.name[i];



                fileName = "/"+files[i];

           $.getJSON(fileName+'.PNG', function(data)
           {


                json[i] = data;
           });
       }
    })

   .done(function()
   {
    makeUL(plan); //doesn't work but needs the data from json[i] in order to continue.
    })

    .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error )
    {
        var err = textStatus + ', ' + error;
        console.log( "Request Failed: " + err);
        alert("failed");
   });
```

Anyone have an idea how I can do this?

Thanks all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [$.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) which can be used for all the promises to complete

```
$.getJSON(file, function (d) {
    var requests = $.map(d.name, function (value, i) {
        files[i] = value;
        var fileName = "/" + value;
        return $.getJSON(fileName + '.PEV', function (data) {
            json[i] = data;
        });
    });

    $.when.apply($, requests).done(function () {
        makeUL(plan);
    });
}).fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
    var err = textStatus + ', ' + error;
    console.log("Request Failed: " + err);
    alert("failed");
});
```

Comment: It seems like this works... You are the man... Thank you so much!

Can you please explain what exactly is going on?  The whole mapping the requests and the files[i]=value with no looping just doing the $.when.apply etc...?

Thanks looks really convenient, so I would like to understand it fully as I'm new to Jquery :).

Comment: @Lasagna the `$.map(d.name, function(){})` does the looping, it returns an array of jQuery ajax promise objects, which is when passed to `$.when` as shown will return a promise object which will be resolved only when all the promises present in the array passed to it is resolved

Comment: I wanted to say thank you for this answer, I forgot to come back and read it as I was really tired when asking this.

Seems like this is a very useful function :)